# How to pass Model data from ViewController to ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, viewmodel, codable

I am modifying my App in order to implement the `MVVM` pattern.

**Introduction:**

I use `WebServices` to get all my data.

At the start of the App, during the loading screen, I make a request to all WebServices so that all my data are available.

For example, when I will tap on the Menu in the App to access a specific Scene, I already have all the data needed, and I pass the model to the corresponding ViewController with the `Segue`.

**The Question:**

The real question is, what is a good way to pass this model data to my `ViewModel`?

I am using a struct that implements the `Codable` protocol to obtain my model after requesting the web service and parsing the json data.

Here is how my ViewController looks like :

```
class VigilanceViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var outletTableView: UITableView!

    var vigilance: Vigilance?

    fileprivate let viewModel = VigilanceViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let vigilance = vigilance {
            // pass data to the viewModel
        }

        outletTableView.dataSource = viewModel
    }
}
```

In the ViewModel, I don't know how to declare the Vigilance model or how to properly initialize the ViewModel.

Here is the ViewModel :

```
class VigilanceViewModel: NSObject {

    var items = [VigilanceViewModelItem]()
    var maxVigilance: Int = 0
    var vigilance: Vigilance? = nil

    override init() {
        super.init()

        // Append objects in my items array from the vigilance Model so that the dataSource is ready to go and clean

    }
}

extension VigilanceViewModel: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return maxVigilance - 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items[section].rowCount
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        // TODO

        return cell
    }
}
```

Because my Model contains a lot of informations that I currently don't need in this ViewController, I am making an items array so that it is easier to use in my `DataSource`.

Here is how my Vigilance Model looks like :

```
struct Vigilance: Codable {

    let result: Result

    struct Result: Codable {
        let startDate: Int
        let endDate: Int
        let sendDate: Int
        let advice: String?
        let comment: String?
        let colorMax: Int
        let details: [VigilanceDetails]?

        struct VigilanceDetails: Codable {
            let dptNumber: String
            let dptName: String
            let color: String
            let risks: [Risks]?

            struct Risks: Codable {
                let code: String
                let label: String
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My first guess on why I can't declare my model without optional is because I don't have custom initializer right ?

But this is not the major issue here.

I would like to know how to pass this model data (previously obtained in this VC from `prepareForSegue`) to the ViewModel, and correctly initialize the ViewModel.

If someone can guide me here it would be really appreciated.

I am exploring some obscur parts of the OS and design patterns, trying my best to understand and apply what I am learning.

Comment: You can configure InitialViewController to be a loading screen and Load in the AppDelegate(“AppController”) your data, then instantiate your contentViewController with its custom initializer and assign it with `window.contentViewController = myContentViewController` to replace the loading screen.

Comment: You have to show SOMETHING in the beginning, and that ViewController will be initialized by the app and so will use `required init(decoder: Decoder)` to load its settings from the Storyboard, so you will not be able to instantiate that with an initializer. All further you can put in xib and instantiate with custom inits (or in storyboards and instantiate with static make-functions where the ViewController settings are set).

Comment: Another tip: Maybe call “ViewModel” sth else, like Model, ModelController, Controller to differentiate what its purpose is(modifying or being the Model). Views can be ViewController and Views, Controllers can be Controllers or ViewControllers. Maybe that distinction is sth just I do though.

Comment: You could also model your State with an enum, which is in the beginning .empty and then you assign your data with `viewModel.state = .data(vigilance: Vigilance)`.

Comment: Are you familiar with the MVVM architecture ?

Comment: Ah that works too, everyone seems to name things differently and its confusing me sometimes. With the help were you able to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first guess on why I can't declare my model without optional is
>   because I don't have custom initializer right ?

As long as you are initiating your UIViewControllers with segues, you won't be able to use a custom initialiser in which you can pass the desired object.
If you want to avoid optional variables, I recommend to write an init function, something like this (and move your VC to a xib file):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let param: String

    init(param: String) {
        self.param = param
        super.init(nibName: "YourViewControllerNibsName", bundle: Bundle.main)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

> The real question is, what is a good way to pass this model data to my ViewModel?

Once you are initiating your view controller from code instead of segues, you can write some helper functions, usually I put it in a Router (or name how you like) class, like:

```
class AppRouter {
    // Return UIViewController not to expose the type of ViewController
    static func getViewController(with param: String) -> UIViewController {
        return ViewController(param: param)
    }
}

// Using it from an another VC
let actualVC: UIViewController!
let vcToPresent = AppRouter.getViewController(with: "yourParam")
actualVC.present(vcToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: And what about the same declaration but in the ViewModel ? (It's actually this one the more important, because the optional in the ViewController, it's just an if let check, not that annoying, but still, thank you for the tip).

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

> And what about the same declaration but in the ViewModel?

```
class VigilanceViewModel: NSObject {
    let items: [VigilanceViewModelItem]
    let maxVigilance: Int
    let vigilance: Vigilance

    init(items: [VigilanceViewModelItem], vigilance: Vigilance) {
        self.items = items
        self.vigilance = vigilance
        maxVigilance = vigilance.max
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but then in the ViewController, how do you pass the vigilance model in the initializer method? fileprivate let viewModel = VigilanceViewModel()

Comment: I just wrote in my other answer, how to initialise a viewcontroller with a parameter. Change `param: String` to `viewModel: VigilanceViewModel` and you'll find the answer